# How close can polynomials be in magnitude?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

If $p$ and $q$ are polynomials and $|p(t)|=|q(t)|$ on the interval $[0,1]$, then in fact $p(t)=\omega q(t)$ for some constant phase $\omega$.

I am curious about quantitative strengthenings of this fact.  For example, suppose that $p$ and $q$ are polynomials (with possibly complex coefficients) of degree $d$ and
$$
\max_{t\in[0,1]}
||p(t)|-|q(t)|| \leq \delta.
$$
When it is possible to conclude that there exist a phase
$\omega\in\mathbb{C}$, $|\omega|=1$, such that
$$
\max_{t\in[0,1]}
|p(t) - \omega q(t)| 
$$
is small?

For example, if $q=1$ and $p_d$ is the Taylor approximation to $e^{it/2}$ given by
$$
p_d(t) = \sum_{j=0}^d \frac{1}{j!}(it/2)^j,
$$
then
$$
\max_{t\in[0,1]} |p_d(t) - e^{it/2}|
\leq C \frac{2^{-d}}{d!},
$$
which means that $||p_d(t)|-1|$ is very small on the interval $[0,1]$, but $p_d$ is also not close to any constant phase.

I suspect for example that this is close to the best possible, meaning that for example if $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ and
$$
\max_{t\in[0,1]} ||p(t)|-1| \leq \delta (Cd)^{-d}
$$
for some large $C$, then it follows that $|p(t)-\omega|$
can be bounded by $\delta$ somehow.  I am curious what bounds are available to this effect.

Comment: Consider $f(t)$ a polynomial which is small on $[0,1/2]$ and $g(t) = f(1-t)$.  For example, $f(t) = (18/5 t - 9/10)^d$.  Take $p(t) = f(t) + g(t)$ and $q(t) = f(t) + \omega g(t)$.  We have that $|p(t)| \approx |q(t)| \forall t \in [0,1]$, but $|p(t) - \omega' q(t)|$ is not small on the entire interval for any phase $\omega'$.

Comment: This is another good example.  I believe that if you normalize the polynomial $f$ so that $\max |f| = 1$, then the maximum value on the interval $[0,1/2]$ must be at least $C^{-d}$ (by the Remez inequality for example).  I am curious whether having $||p|-|q|| < (Cd)^{-d}$ (after normalizing $|q|$ so that its maximum is $1$) is small enough to ensure that $p\approx \omega q$.